# CreateFileA returning invalid handle when file exists

Tags: windows, ollydbg, winapi

I was working on a practice binary. It opens the file at C:/WINDOWS/system32/filename#123.dat, if the file does not exist, the check compares the result to -1 (An invalid handle). However, even after creating the file, then re-running (Using ollydbg) the handle value is still invalid (-1). I am following a walk-through where the individual goes through the exact same steps. and a valid handle is returned. I am running as administrator. Is this a known issue? Anyone have a solution to it? Been stuck for 2 days

File being accessed via:

```
CreateFileA
Access = GENERIC_READ
ShareMode = 0
pSecurity= NULL
Mode = OPEN_EXISTING
Attributes = NORMAL
hTemplateFile = NULL
FileName = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\filename#123.dat"
```

I originally tried on Windows 10, did not work, so then I hopped over to windows XP 64 bit (what the walkthrough was using - still did not work.)

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. I suppose the fact that you do this in a debugger makes it somewhat **on**-topic. But so far you're not even giving us the full picture. What's the last error code when it fails to give you a valid handle?

Comment: Look up Wow64 fs redirection

Answer (score -1):

Found solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64109842/reopenfile-windows-api-fails-with-error-invalid-name-when-reopening-a-file-in

Fix: Ran the binary on 32 architecture windows XP